# silverstripe documentation for beginners

Tags: php, silverstripe

I Am new To SilverStripe , but i like to learn it From Sketch.
I know there are many resources such as  their manual.
but i want to know resources like video tutorials and source codes like material youtube channels etc.

Comment: Where have you looked? The official documentation has a step by step tutorial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tutorials: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/

Reference: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/

Topics: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/

API: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/